# backbone js Todo Code not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Iam learning Backbone JS, why my below code not displaying in browser? I even used routers, but still not displaying in browser. Please tell me what went wrong. BTW, output just displaying in Console only. Sorry if its dumb query.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*$.getJSON('api/users/1',function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });*/
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
                toggleStatus: function(){
                    if(this.get('status') == 'incomplete'){
                        this.set({'status':'complete'});
                    } else {
                        this.set({'status':'incomplete'});
                    }
                }
            })

            var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
                template: _.template('<h3> ' +'<input type=checkbox ' +'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +' <%= description %></h3>'),
                render: function(){
                    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                },
                events: {
                    'change imput': 'toggleStatus'
                },
                toggleStatus : function(){
                    this.model.toggleStatus();  
                }
            })


            var todoItem = new TodoItem({ description: 'Pick up milk', status: 'incomplete', id: 1 });
            var todoView = new TodoView({model: todoItem});


            console.log(todoView.el);

            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    '': 'home'
                }
            });
            var router = new Router();
            router.on('route:home' , function(){
                    todoView.render();
            });

            Backbone.history.start();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view should render in one of this fashions ,  when You want create new element, specify tagName, className  and id, and when  need an element to append view to It you should specify el to select it (jquery selects it). Next issue of Your code is that you do not return this in the render function. when You have nested views , You should return this.

I have tested it in this bin
http://jsbin.com/jefuyuxanu/2/edit

Comment: Just a doubt.. I heard 'el' default value is DIV tag, so then why to declare el:'#test'  ?

Comment: I have mentioned there are two approach for create a view. First You want create an abstract view so can render It anywhere on the fly.  Second You have a predefined placeholder to render it. You said right. default value for el is DIV but when the selected el is not in the DOM It can not be rendered and attach to DOM. So el reference must be refer to an exist DOM element to inline rendering. If you do not define an existed DOM element, view can be rendered on the fly but not shown, and You can attach It manually to an pre-rendered element(placeholder).

Comment: Sorry to ask same query again.. My actual doubt is: If 'el' default value is DIV tag and I guess DIV tag will be in DOM only, Right??  so why not it displays  if we do not specify 'el' value? Kindly understand my query...

Comment: All views have a DOM element at all times (the el property), whether they've already been inserted into the page or not. In this fashion, views can be rendered at any time, and inserted into the DOM all at once, in order to get high-performance UI rendering with as few reflows and repaints as possible. this.el is created from the view's tagName, className, id and attributes properties, if specified. If not, el is an empty div. ( From Backbone site)

Comment: In my opinion, You have confused, beacase DIV is default value for tagName not el. In general you have two way. 1. Define el for an exist DOM element. 2. Define tagName, className and id for  dom element that unavailiable yet. so empty div created by backbone because you havent specified el. and next important tip you should know is html elements should attach to the DOM to get visibility. DOM Element must attach to DOM Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your TodoView isn't appended into DOM .

set "el" attribute for your view

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'body',
    template: _.template('<h3> ' +'<input type=checkbox ' +'<% if(status === "complete") print("checked") %>/>' +' <%= description %></h3>'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        'change imput': 'toggleStatus'
    },
    toggleStatus : function(){
        this.model.toggleStatus();  
    }
})
```

Comment: Just a doubt.. I heard 'el' default value is DIV tag, so then why to declare el:'body'?